# MacOS, Sleep Wake Failure

Tags: macbook, macos-highsierra

I have a problem with my MacBook Pro.
OS High Sierra installed. I plug out power cable and use laptop normally, then connect to charge. After a while, the laptop resets and an error occurs -

> Data Source:     Stackshots
>
> Event:           Sleep Wake Failure Duration:        0.08s Steps:
>   7
>
> Hardware model:  MacBookPro11,5 Active cpus:     8
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 120000s

It happens every time.
How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

After upgrade to Mojave I didn't see this problem.